# Where on Earth is this manor-house-looking structure?

Tags: where-on-earth, identify-this

My friend sent me this and I can't seem to find it on Google. My friend likes traveling so it probably is a tourist spot.

[image]

Comment: I assume you want a more specific answer but I'd say it's in the UK.

Comment: Can't you ask your friend?

Comment: Never mind where it is - what is the ghostly apparition standing in front of it??

Comment: I lost contact of him two years ago. He might be dead.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Google Image Search identifies this as the front of the [University of Sydney's main building](https://www.google.dk/maps/place/The+University+of+Sydney/@-33.8857366,151.1897304,3a,75y,259.55h,97.57t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-4HNJ-I3O4nI%2FVk5Popq4e6I%2FAAAAAAAA9KA%2FUeWbyZlLlNMkc60Oq56Oy5EpV3-edcodQCLIB!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh6.googleusercontent.com%2F-4HNJ-I3O4nI%2FVk5Popq4e6I%2FAAAAAAAA9KA%2FUeWbyZlLlNMkc60Oq56Oy5EpV3-edcodQCLIB%2Fw203-h100-k-no-pi-0-ya220.32892-ro-0-fo100%2F!7i10240!8i5120!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x0:0x1d017d69037a07c0!2sThe+University+of+Sydney!8m2!3d-33.888584!4d151.1873473!3m4!1s0x0:0x1d017d69037a07c0!8m2!3d-33.888584!4d151.1873473).

Comment: Odd, I thought google always blurred faces in google map pics

Comment: @Albert Note this isn't a standard Street View image, rather it's a user contributed photo sphere

Answer (score 14):

Henning Makholm is right regarding the University of Sydney: you can browse and use the view points on campus map:
https://sydney.edu.au/campus-life/getting-to-campus.html
[image: Camperdown Campus]

Comment: What does this answer add that the other answer doesn't have?